# A-frame mobile scaling

Tags: three.js, aframe, aspect-ratio

I can't seem to figure out why the mobile view of a-frame camera aspect ratio is completely off. it's scaled so everything looks skinny in portrait mode and wide in landscape. I am also getting this error in console:

> dpdb.js:79 Failed to recalculate device parameters.

I've adjusted the CSS and set the canvas width/height on a settimeout after it renders. Any way around this issue?

Comment: You will need to provide what device and browser you are using. It is probably because the webvr-polyfill does not know about the screen size of your device.

Comment: ios 11.2.1, iphone X, safari

getting the same issue when using latest version of chrome on OSX 10.12.4

Comment: This is a screenshot (https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/3j2c3N0q3X3K0E1u2h3g/Image%202017-12-22%20at%2010.42.30%20PM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=43fdd36d954962bf751395609bd11b8a&v=d0c28773) from the examples in the A-Frame site running on an iPhone X. You can see that the aspect ratio is correct (https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/360-image-gallery/) in landscape orientation. You will have to share more info about the content you are running.